# Is $\varphi : \mathbb{R}_{2 \times 2}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{4}$ onto?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

The question was to decide whether $\varphi$ is a linear transformation – I've checked and properly shown that it is in fact a linear transformation. Now I'm trying to decide whether it's isomorphic.

I've checked for injection - everything checks out but I got stuck at evaluating surjection.

$\varphi : \mathbb{R}_{2 \times 2}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{4}$ is defined as $\varphi\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\ 
c & d
\end{bmatrix}=(a,-a+c,d,b)$.

We have been taught that when checking for surjection, we're trying to figure whether for every vector $v$ there is a vector $u$ such that $\varphi(v) = u$.

So I tried to show that for every $\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\ 
c & d
\end{bmatrix}$ there is $\begin{bmatrix}
x & y \\ 
z & w
\end{bmatrix}$ such that $\varphi\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\ 
c & d
\end{bmatrix}=(a,-a+c,d,b)=\begin{bmatrix}
x & y \\ 
z & w
\end{bmatrix}$.

And I got stuck here (or confused even?) and I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Use `2 \times 2` to get $2 \times 2$

Comment: Recall that an injective linear map is surjective, hence is bijective, when working with two finite-dimensional vector spaces of the same dimension.

Comment: To show that $\phi$ is surjective, show that for every $(m,n,p,q)\in \mathbb R^4$ there is $\pmatrix{x&y\\z&w}\in \mathbb R_{2\times2}$  such that $\phi\pmatrix{x&y\\z&w}=(m,n,p,q)$

Comment: If you are given $a$ and $-a +c$, you can recover $c$ and then you're there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $(x,y,z,w)\in\mathbb{R}^4$. Then, $\varphi\left(\begin{bmatrix}
x & w \\ 
y+x & z
\end{bmatrix}\right)=(x,-x+(y-x),z,w)=(x,y,z,w),$ so $\varphi$ is onto.

Alternatively, as the dimension of $\mathbb{R}_{2\times 2}$ and $\mathbb{R}^4$ is the same (and equal to $4$), checking either injectivity or surjectivity directly implies the other.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing elements of $\Bbb R_{2\times 2}$ and $\Bbb R^4$.

To check surjectivity you need to begin with $u = (w,x,y,z)$ and find $v =\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\ 
c & d
\end{bmatrix}$ such that $\varphi(v) = u$

Answer (score 0):

Say there is some $\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\ 
c & d
\end{bmatrix}$ such that $\varphi\left(\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\ 
c & d
\end{bmatrix}\right)=(0,0,0,0)$. Then one sees that $(a,c-a,d,b)=(0,0,0,0)$, and this makes it clear that $\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\ 
c & d
\end{bmatrix}$ must be the zero matrix of order 2. Therefore $\varphi$ is injective. Since $\dim(\mathbb R_{2\times 2})=\dim(\mathbb R^4)$ as $\mathbb R$-vector spaces, surjectivity follows.